# How to manipulate ngfor table, to toggle between two arrays

Tags: arrays, angular, ngfor

I would like to know if there is a simple way of parsing different array to a single *ngfor table. I have the below codes:

**.html**

```
<div class="mb-3">
        <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="date" (click)="valid()" />
            <label class="form-check-label">Valid</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="date" (click)="invalid()"/>
            <label class="form-check-label">Invalid</label>
        </div>
</div>

<tr *ngFor="let myAccount of Account | filterBy: accountFilter | paginate: { itemsPerPage: count, currentPage: p }; let i = index">
            <td>{{ (p - 1) * count + i + 1 }}</td>
            <td>{{myAccount.name}}</td>
            <td>{{myAccount.startDate}}</td>
            <td>{{myAccount.endDate}}</td>
</tr>
```

**.ts**

```
Account = [];
radioAccount = [];
currentDate = '';

ngOnInit() {
    showAll();
}
showAll() {
       return this.acctService.getAccount().subscribe(data => this.Account = data);
}

valid() {
        this.currentDate = this.datePipe.transform(new Date(),"yyyy-MM-dd");
        this.radioAccount = this.Account.filter(data => {
            return data.startDate < this.currentDate  && data.endDate > this.currentDate});
}

invalid() {
    this.currentDate = this.datePipe.transform(new Date(),"yyyy-MM-dd");
    this.radioAccount = this.Account.filter(data => {
        return data.startDate < this.currentDate  && data.endDate <= this.currentDate});
}
```

You can see that I have two arrays, how do I display content of "radioAccount" array when a radio button is clicked? That is, the possibility of swiching between "Account" content and "radioAccount" content. I don't think repeating the *ngfor code with *ngif is a solution.

Comment: you should be doing the filtering  of data by sending it to the server , same goes for the pagination too. Otherwise if you have 10000+ records and you are retrieving 10 rows in each call you will be only applying the filter on 10 records.  there is no need to switch the array for any reason , just load the new data into same array

Comment: https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/06/18/angular-8-simple-pagination-example

Comment: @JoelJoseph, I am not doinging pagination. I am filtering the data that my service returned using radio button. When my app loads, I got all data and want to filter the data with radio buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an array which will not be filtered, e.g., `AccountSource` and then you can assign original values (`AccountSource`) to `Account`:

```
Account = [];
AccountSource= [];

showAll() {
   return this.acctService.getAccount()
       .subscribe(data => {
            this.Account = data;
            this.AccountSource = data;
       });
}

valid() {
        this.currentDate = this.datePipe.transform(new Date(),"yyyy-MM-dd");
        this.Account = this.Account.filter(data => {
            return data.startDate < this.currentDate  && data.endDate > this.currentDate});
}

invalid() {
    this.currentDate = this.datePipe.transform(new Date(),"yyyy-MM-dd");
    this.Account = this.Account.filter(data => {
        return data.startDate < this.currentDate  && data.endDate <= this.currentDate});
}

setSourceData() {
    this.Account = this.AccountSource;
}
```

and call `setSourceData()` method whenever you want to see original values.

Comment: While this was a good idea, you did not need to restructure the whole code. What I did was to add "this.AccountSource = data;" like you wrote and the filter "AccountSource" instead of "Account" and the code works. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @Pleasure I am glad that it helped to you!:)